# JavaScript onchange not working on dropdown element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating an application that will search db and later on allow user to compare results. For that i need multiple dependable drop down menus. I am not expert coder, have some knowledge of HTML and PHP. For this i have to use Javascript.

Now if i try to use same script with diferent information that will create dropdown3, it does not work.

Here is code of index page:

```
<?php
require('assets/classes/manufacturer.php');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="dropdown1">
                <select name="proizvodac" id="proizvodac-select">
                    <option value="">Odaberi Proizvođača</option>
                    <?php foreach($proizvodaci as $proizvodac): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $proizvodac['id']; ?>"><?php echo $proizvodac['proizvodac']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown2">
        </div> 

        <div id="dropdown3">
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div id="grupe">
        <div id="grupa1">
        </div>
        <div id="grupa2">
        </div>
        <div id="grupa3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And script is here:

```
$('#proizvodac-select').on('change', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/assets/classes/model.php',
        data: { proizvodac: self.val()},
        success: function(data){
                $('#dropdown2').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This should call model.php when selection is made in first dropdown, first dropdown is created from manufacturer.php that is required on start.

model.php:

```
<?php
require('database.php');
if(isset($_GET['proizvodac'])) {
    $modelQuery = "SELECT 
                        * 
                    FROM auti 
                    WHERE proizvodac_id = :proizvodac_id
    ";
    $modeli = $db->prepare($modelQuery);

    $modeli->execute(['proizvodac_id' => $_GET['proizvodac']]);

    $selectedModel = $modeli->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>
         <select name="model" id="model-select">
            <option value="">Odaberi Model</option>
            <?php foreach($modeli as $model): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $model['id']; ?>"><?php echo    $model['model']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

NOTE:
I have probably did something wrong when i was trying to create third dropdown that depends on second one.

EDIT: I have did something wrong, thanks  kingkero for finding it.

So what i need now, if you can tell me how to get third dropdown menu and so on. I need like 10 of them. All should depend on previous one.
And if you notice some bad practice in my code, please let me know.

Now i got script for third dropdown and it is working if run from console in chrome but can't get it to work by itself.

SCRIPT HERE:

```
$('#model-select').on('change', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/assets/classes/opcija_modela.php',
        data: { model: self.val()},
        success: function(data){
                $('#dropdown3').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're writing into `#dropdown2-value` but that id doesn't exist anywhere. To see if the AJAX itself is working, open your developer console and go to network. Then change the value and you should see the request + all information of it (like response data and success/failure)

Comment: Thank you @kingkero, first problem solved, can't belive i missed it. Now i have this other problem, Edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Your Script file should be include with in the head tag

Ex:

```html
<?php
require('assets/classes/manufacturer.php');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="dropdown1">
                <select name="proizvodac" id="proizvodac-select">
                    <option value="">Odaberi Proizvođača</option>
                    <?php foreach($proizvodaci as $proizvodac): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $proizvodac['id']; ?>"><?php echo $proizvodac['proizvodac']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown2">
        </div> 

        <div id="dropdown3">
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div id="grupe">
        <div id="grupa1">
        </div>
        <div id="grupa2">
        </div>
        <div id="grupa3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```